# i want store (array- of object- of array value )in variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
gstPercent: "25"
hsnCode: "856657089900"
idata: null
materialCode: "212321"
materialName: "216465132"
pricing: {pricingHistory: [
salesPricing: 1235
 ]
}
status: true
```

given data

and am trying:

```js
var sellingPrice = matListOfOne.find(p => p.pricing.pricingHistory.filter(function (s){
    return s.salesPricing;
}));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Is the filter just supposed to return any salesPricing set?

Answer (score 0):

The array should contain numerous sting values or objects.

The correct json should be :

```
gstPercent: "25",
hsnCode: "856657089900",
idata: null,
materialCode: "212321",
materialName: "216465132",
pricing: {pricingHistory:[
{salesPricing: '1235'}
 ]
}
```

Your code should work now

Comment: its throwing undefind of variable which am trying to filter from pricing(object) of pricingHistory of value sales price  that code doesnt work!! even its contain string values or objects,

Answer (score 0):

this works
//storing pricing obj in varibale

```
var pricing = oneMatData.find(function (p) {
                return p.pricing;` `
            }).pricing;
```

var salesPricing = pricing.pricingHistory[0].salesPricing;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).